# What is the correct way of managing views on playn?

Tags: gwt, playn

I am at the very early days of my journey with playn. I am actually iOS developer and want to use playn. I want to transform the game which is already on App Store. I normally used navigation controller on my iOS game.

The schema is like:
Menu
  Play Now
    Classic Game
    Fast Mode
High Scores
  Classic Scores
  Fast Mode Scores
.
.
.

Now I started to add grouplayers (views actually) to graphics().rootLayer(). But I want to add animation to these views like iPhone applications. Is this the correct way of managing views on a game?

PS. I saw the tripleplay library has some objects like screenstack. But the samples are not using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ScreenStack is definitely designed for managing the sorts of things you're talking about. Check out the source code to the game [Atlantis](http://github.com/threerings/atlantis) for an example of the use of the screen stack.

The samples try to avoid the use of third party libraries just to remain simple.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I could not manage to run Atlantis yet. It asks for tripleplay 1.2 but I could only find 1.1. The game is running but i cannot click main menu.